# Kitchen sink drain pipe leaking inside the wall

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, leak

I'm remodeling my kitchen and installed the new sink this week but noticed that any time the water runs, water emerges from inside the wall, near the drain pipe and as a result, the fiberglass insulation gets wet. Not sure what I did to cause it but I'm guessing the drain pipe is cracked.

Is this something I can repair/replace myself or do I need a plumber for this job? I'd like to think I'm fairly handy and have the tools; just not sure what this process would entail.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Might as well open up the wall and have a look - you'll have to open up the wall to fix it anyway, and repair the wall when fixed (make sure the fix does not leak before you repair the wall, though.) If you do that and assess that it feels out of your comfort zone, at least you won't be paying plumber labor rates for ripping the wall open.

Answer (score 2):

As Ecnerwall stated break open the wall to locate exactly where the leak is coming from. A common plumbing orientation that you may notice inside your wall is for the trap pipe after entering the wall will connect to the center of a [Tee fitting](https://www.ferguson.com/product/connectite-1-12-in-hub-dwv-and-sanitary-schedule-40-abs-tee-adwvstj/_/R-20834). The top connection is the drain vent (which goes to the roof) and the bottom leads the water to the main drain pipe.

Depending on what fitting/connection is leaking you will need to remove and replace it.

ABS pipe and fittings are welded together (just like PVC) with an ABS glue. If you are comfortable with cutting out the fitting and/or pipe the repair is fairly straight forward.

It sometimes helps to enlarge the wall opening as this allows more movement of the pipes and gives you more freedom to work.

There are fittings called "No-Hubs" which are basically rubber fittings that need no glue and are tightened by a hose clamp. These are much more forgiving and can be re-positioned anytime. They're sized for 1 1/2"-4" pipes and are commonly found as couplings, but also Tee's.